# VBA 6.5 - "Bad File Name or Number" error on Form.Show - Run-time Error 52

Tags: forms, vba, excel

EDIT: This ended up being more of a "how does the MS VBA IDE work?" kind of question. It was highlighting a function call when it erred out, but it was a line of code within the function actually causing the issue. By using the "Step Into" and "Step Over" actions (F8 and Shift+F8 respectively by default), you can walk through your code until you find the line that actually caused the error. Trying to step over *this* line will cause the VBA IDE to go back to the initially-highlighted line of code.

---

I have a simple VBA user form I've developed for use with Microsoft Excel 2007. A button on one of my sheets shows this form using the following lines of VBA:

```
Sub ShowMyDialog()
    MyFormName.Show
End Sub
```

This was working perfectly fine yesterday. Today I open the .xlsm file and click the button to show the form again, and I get a "Run-time Error 52: Bad File Name or Number" error.

When I click "Debug" it just takes me to the line in which I'm showing the form above. The name is correct, and this hasn't changed since the last time it was in a working state. My form *does* open files from a directory, but if this were the problem, wouldn't it direct me to the line of code doing the file opening?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you show more code pleasE?

Comment: It is a problem with path or file.  Check your drive for errors, too.

Comment: This is the entire contents of the module that is being activated on the button press on my Excel sheet, and this is where it's pointing when I hit "debug" on the error. Is it possible for the error to be somewhere within the form code even though it's stopping me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *My form does open files from a directory, but if this were the problem, wouldn't it direct me to the line of code doing the file opening?*

Not without an error handler, and not without error handling configured to break in classes. The code you posted is irrelevant to the issue and isn't causing the error.

Your form has some code that runs on load/initialization/activation, which fails opening a file, as the error message says.

Any code that's accessing outside resources **must** have error handling.

```
Private Sub DoSomething
On Error GoTo CleanFail

    DoSomethingThatCanBlowUp

CleanExit:
    Exit Sub

CleanFail:
    ' handle errors here
End Sub
```

Comment: That On Error command only handles the line beneath is correct? Is it possible to apply a single On Error to an entire block without declaring a separate function?

Comment: That was definitely the solution. The constructor for my form has some code that's *supposed* to check for file existence, but it was breaking. Since I'm only hiding and showing the form, that also explains why it broke between yesterday and today. The form already existed and it wasn't calling that constructor.

Comment: `On Error` applies to an entire *scope*

Comment: Aha! Additionally, Error blocks can *kind of* be established by using `On Error GoTo [error handling label] [ code that could throw errors ] On Error GoTo 0`